# remove_pointer + typename is error

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I'm not sure why I am getting an error on this line.

I am compiling with

```
$CPP -g -std=c++0x -Wall
```

Where $CPP is g++-4.7. I am including type_traits (C++11, not boost). Is this not supported yet in 4.7.2?

```
typedef typename remove_pointer<typename T>::type &U;
```

Error

```
file.h:222:44: error: template argument 1 is invalid
file.h:222:19: error: expected nested-name-specifier
file.h:222:47: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
file.h:222:47: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
file.h:222:53: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘U’ with no type [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Could you show the code around this statement? Such as where `T` comes from?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That syntax is definitely ill-formed in C++11. If `T` is an in-scope template type parameter, you should remove the `typename` before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `typename` in `typename T` is incorrect; `typename` is only to be used on dependent names.  Write:

```
typedef typename remove_pointer<T>::type &U;
```